# c# check if list contains a null element and do not list entire line in a for statement

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I have a list which lines contain a string + variable, what im trying to figure out is if the variable is null how not to list the line in the for statement.

What im trying to figure out is if device.State = null how not to display the entire line?

```
 string[] deviceQuery =
            {
                                "Device State: " + device.State,
                "ADB Version: " + adbVersion,
                "ADB Running Version: " + adbServer.GetStatus(),
                "ADB Server Status: " + adbStatus.ToString(),
                "ADB Default Server Port: " + AdbClient.AdbServerPort,
                "ADB Default Port: " + AdbClient.DefaultPort,
                "ADB Default Encoding: " + AdbClient.DefaultEncoding,
                "Device Serial: " + device.Serial,
                "Device Model: " + device.Model,
                "Product Name: " + device.Product,
                "Device Name: " + deviceName,
                "Product Features: " + device.Features,
                "Device USB Port: " + device.Usb,
                "Transport ID: " + device.TransportId,
                "Device Message: " + device.Message,
                "Connection Endpoint: " + AdbClient.DefaultEndPoint.ToString(),
                "Connection Serialization: " + AdbClient.DefaultEndPoint.Serialize(),
                "Connection Type: " + AdbClient.DefaultEndPoint.GetType()
            }

 List<string> deviceStatus = new List<string>(deviceQuery);

 for (int i = 0; i < deviceStatus.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (deviceStatus != null && deviceStatus.Any(p => p != null))
                            {
                                SetText(deviceStatus[i]);
                            }
                        
                    }
```

```
Device State: Online
ADB Version: 31
ADB Running Version: Version 1.0.31 of the adb daemon is running.
ADB Server Status: The adb daemon is not running.
ADB Default Server Port: 5037
ADB Default Port: 5555
ADB Default Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Device Serial: G070L82402250UDU
Device Model: AFTT
Product Name: full_tank
Device Name:
Product Features:
Device USB Port:
Transport ID:
Device Message:
Connection Endpoint: 127.0.0.1:5555
Connection Serialization: InterNetwork:16:{21,179,127,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
Connection Type: System.Net.IPEndPoint
```

Comment: How is your device list look like ? Why you are creating deviceQuery string of Array  ?

Comment: _Lines contain a string + variable_ meaning what? Is the string alwqays the same? Can the 'variable' be anything?Show an example line! Your code tests the whole list to be not null which it shouldn't be anyway..

Comment: I shortened the list so i didnt clutter the question but the list has about 40 item in a similar structure

Comment: Some if the variables in that list return null depending on the type of device, I want to filter out those lines from being displayed in SetText().

Comment: So no entry in that list is null because there is always, at least, the  string constant before the colon. Right?

Comment: Yes, but what is the content? Is device.State a number`? If it is unique you can split at " :" and test the length of the 2nd element.. If it is null or empty you fopund an nvalid line.

Comment: @Steve Exactly!!!

Comment: Then you should work on the part the fills the list. When one of the variables returns a null  replace it with some unique identifier, then you check for the presence of the identifier and skip that line

Comment: @Steve thats what im not sure how to do im new to c# its killing me right now lol I just want the entire line not to display.

Comment: `string line = deviceStatus [i]; var parts = line.Split(new string[] { ": " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (parts.Length < 2 || parts[1].Length == 0) Console.WriteLine("error in line: " + line);
`

Comment: new (string prefix, object value)[]
            {
                ("Device State: ", null),
                ("ADB Version: ", "adbVersion"),
                ("ADB Running Version: ", "adbServer.GetStatus()"),
                ("ADB Server Status: ", null),
                ("ADB Default Server Port: ", "AdbClient.AdbServerPort"),
                ("ADB Default Port: ", "AdbClient.DefaultPort")
            }
            .Where(x => x.value != null)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => SetText($"{x.prefix}{x.value}"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would only know at runtime, you can't use an array. Use the `List<string>` directly instead.

Now, make a method:

```
void AddIfNotNull(List<string> list, string prefix, object suffix)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
    }

    if (suffix == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    list.Add(prefix + suffix);
}
```

I suppose we we can create a generic version of that. However, I'm not going to bother (if you know the type, you figure that out). Instead, I will make a version that takes tuples:

```
void AddIfNotNull(List<string> list, (string prefix, object suffix) line)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
    }

    if (line.suffix == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    list.Add(line.prefix + line.suffix);
}
```

Sorry, I meant tuples, plural:

```
void AddIfNotNull(List<string> list, IEnumerable<(string prefix, object suffix)> lines)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
    }

    if (lines == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lines));
    }
    
    foreach (var (prefix, suffix) in lines)
    {
        if (suffix == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        list.Add(prefix + suffix);
    }
}
```

Now we can use it like this:

```
var list = new List<String>();
AddIfNotNull
(
    list,
    new []
    {
        ("Device State: ", device.State),
        ("Something", new object()),
        ("Some other", null),
    }
);
```

I suppose that since you are going to concatenate anyway, you could work with `string?` (that is define the tuple type as `(string prefix, string? suffix)`), then using `.?toString()` would be handy.

Another way you could take this is to not concatenate them until you need to output them. In fact, why a list and not a `Dictionary`? Well, that is up to you.

---

Handling empty string and white-space:

```
void AddIfNotNull(List<string> list, IEnumerable<(string prefix, string? suffix)> lines)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
    }

    if (lines == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lines));
    }
    
    foreach (var (prefix, suffix) in lines)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suffix))
        {
            continue;
        }

        list.Add(prefix + suffix);
    }
}
```

Comment: would I add the lines like this -> ("Device State: ", device.State),

Comment: @demo7up yes, that is the idea

Comment: im getting an error for the list new[] No best type found for implicitly typed array.

Comment: @demo7up I don't know your types. You could specify `new (string prefix, object suffix)[]{/*...*/}` or however you have it defined.

Comment: the output is the same I have added to the question above.

Comment: @demo7up I'm guessing those are not null, just empty string, or whitespace... Edit: updated answer. Ah, I have an error, let me fix that... Edit: fixed (I had prefix where I should have had suffix).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment above. You can leverage the null propagation operator and the null coalescing operator to insert a special character in your strings if the input variable is null.

```
string[] deviceQuery =
         {
             // if device or device.State are null the result will be "Device State: @
             "Device State: " + (device?.State ?? "@"),
             ....
```

Now, before setting the text check if the special character is present or not in your strings

```
for (int i = 0; i < deviceStatus.Count; i++)
{
      if (!deviceStatus[i].Contains("@"))
      {
          SetText(deviceStatus[i]);
      }
    
}
```

Of course if the character @ is an expected value for your variables then you should change it to something that will never appear in your input variables